# Change the direction of the readers and writers in FME

Tags: fme-form

Is it possible in FME to change the dataflow direction from:

Reading datasource A and writing to datasource B

to

Read datasource B and write to datasource A

And between the reading and writing you use many different kind of transformers. This meaning FME would have to do som kind of reverse engineer to be able to go the opposite way in all the transformers.

Comment: That would depend on the specific datafiles involved.  Please **edit** your question to be less hypothetical.

Comment: Can you specify what you are trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response.
I would say the issue would be the transformers, not what kind of format on the writer or reader?
I havn't done any work yet, so it is just a hypothetical question for now. But for example can you reverse a datflow going from postgresql db via a Attributesplitter transformer into a oracle db?

Comment: They way I've done this is to add both a reader and writer for each data source/output you want and enable/disable them accordingly. As @blord-castillo mentioned in the answer below, there is no 'reverse data flow' function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could almost certainly write a separate workspace to "reverse" your original workspace, FME does not have a way to directly reverse the flow of a workspace. Realistically, there could be many workspaces involving [geometric operators](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Categories/geometric_operators.htm%3FTocPath%3DFME%2520Transformers%7CGeometric%2520Operators%7C_____0) that are not reversible.
e.g. there is no way to reverse the output of the [Dissolver Transformer](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/dissolver.htm) without having additional information about the original state of the dataset before dissolving.

Comment: Thats what I thought. But I was hoping that perhaps FME had made it somewhat easier. But as youo say, some transformer make it impossible to do a "reverse".
But now I dont have to wondeirng about this anymore, big thanks for the help.
Br
Mike

Answer (score 0):

One simple use case is where you want to back up a bunch of tables, then truncate the tables and run some ddl sql to change, say number columns to char columns, and then restore the tables.